# Using one adjective ("contagious") to describe two words

Tags: adjectives

Please tell me - is it correct in English to say:

> Intelligence is contagious, as well is stupidity.

It's intended for a simple Instagram post. It just came into my mind. I wanted to describe the influence of good and bad things.

Comment: Why would you think "contagious" is a good word here?  Have you looked it up?

Comment: Can you edit your post to make it clearer what you are concerned about? Do you want input on the use of the structure "as well as stupidity" to indicate that stupidity is also contagious without repeating the adjective?

Comment: Almost. After the comma you should either write *as well as...* or *as is...*

Comment: Would you consider 'John is tall, as is Jane' incorrect?

Comment: @Xanne, It's intended for a simple Instagram post. 
It just came into my mind. 
I wanted to describe the influence of good and bad things.

Comment: @sumelic I think you wrote the message before "Dog Lover" edited my question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please check my previous answer to "Xanne", there I explain for what is the message intended.

Comment: This is half-way between being correct and meaning "intelligence is stupidity."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct.

It would be correct to say "Intelligence is contagious, as is stupidity" --although that's a nonsensical statement.

@EdwinAshworth gave you the correct formulation in his comment "John is tall, as is Jane."

Comment: Agreed. The original post phrase is not correct. And since you don't know whether intelligence is indeed contagious, you might hedge your bets with the intriguing "If intelligence is contagious then so is stupidity."

Comment: 'It's raining cats and dogs' is a 'nonsensical statement', but totally acceptable in non-formal registers.